# Python com MYSQL - ERRO: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: mysql, python

Estou tentando praticar criando um pequeno programa com TELA DE LOGIN.
Esse programa tem acesso a um banco de dados MYSQL e quero fazer a VALIDAÇÃO dos dados de login para permitir a entrada.

Estou tentando aprender sozinho e tendo muitas dificuldades.
Acontece que quando eu tento entrar com um usuario que já existe no banco, mas erro a senha, o programa funciona normal.
Porém, quando tento um LOGIN que não está no banco, o programa exibe esse erro. Não consegui encontrar solução ainda.

```
login_user = tela_login.lineEdit.text()
senha_user = tela_login.lineEdit_2.text()

cursor = banco.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT senha FROM quadro_funcionarios WHERE login = '{}'".format(login_user))
senha_banco = cursor.fetchone()

if senha_user == senha_banco[0]:
    tela_login.close()
    menu_principal.show()
```

O erro gerado é este:

```
 22     senha_banco = cursor.fetchone()
 23 
 24     if senha_user == senha_banco[0]: #Erro nesta linha aqui.
 25         tela_login.close()
 26         menu_principal.show()
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Estou procurando em todo canto, como solucionar, mas não entendo o erro.

Comment: provavelmente o valor de senha_banco é `None`.

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta para incluir sua query, e explicar melhor o problema.

Comment: Obrigado. Acabei de fazer isso.

Comment: Tu ta buscando um usuário que NÃO EXISTE no teu banco. Tu tem que verificar se vem algo ali. Provavelmente vem um `None` como o @Danizavtz comentou. Ai tu ta tentando acessar um `None[0]`, faz sentido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece quando você está acessando o índice de um objeto que é `None`.

```py
spam = None

print(spam[0])
# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Considerando que no seu código existe apenas o `senha_banco[0]`, então `senha_banco` é None.

Verificando a documentação do [`fetchone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) você tem:

> This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, **or None if no more rows are available**.

Ou seja, ele pode retornar `None` quando não há nenhum registro para ser retornado. No seu caso, tudo indica que não foi encontrado o registro com o login informado.

Você pode validar isso com o `rowcount`:

```py
if cursor.rowcount == 0:
  raise Exception(f'Nenhum registro encontrado com o login {login_user}')
```

Mas será interessante você debugar o código e certificar-se se o registro existe, ou não, no banco de dados.